# Sencha Touch before/after build hooks reference

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is there a list or reference of all the possible 'commands' (tags) we could set on before/after build hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can see them in your project directory at .sencha/app/build-impl.xml

Comment: Thanks, but I think what Im looking for is not there. I would like to have a complete reference of what we could do from target.. ie: I know we can: <copy todir="${x.location}"><fileset dir="${build.dir}" /></copy> or we can: <delete dir="${build.dir}"/> so, can we move/rename? (its just an example)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of documentation links for Sencha Command from the Sencha website:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/command_advanced

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/command_compiler

Comment: Thanks - but not what I was looking for. Please read my comment on @shepsii answer.